# Group by month and return months where result is 0 filtering by year

Tags: mysql, date, aggregate

I'm trying to group by month the results of a given table and return where there are no values, I have created another table, but I can't filter the entries by year (say, `where YEAR(created) = 2018`), but the inner query isn't returning the months as expected.

I've got this query.

```
SELECT 
    months.name as m, 
    count(MONTH(created_at)) as total 
from entries 
RIGHT JOIN months 
    ON MONTH(created_at) = months.id 
where YEAR(created_at) = 2018 
GROUP BY months.id
```

The result of the query is this:

```
+----+------------------+---------------------------+
| id | month            | total                     |
+----+------------------+---------------------------+
|  1 | january          | 27                        |
|  3 | march            | 3                         |
|  5 | may              | 2                         |
+----+------------------+---------------------------+
```

And I want to achieve the following:

```
+----+------------------+-------+
| id | month            | total |
+----+------------------+-------+
|  1 | january          | 27    |
|  2 | february         | 0     |
|  3 | march            | 3     |
|  4 | april            | 0     |
|  5 | may              | 2     |
|  6 | june             | 0     |
|  7 | july             | 0     |
|  8 | august           | 0     |
|  9 | september        | 0     |
| 10 | october          | 0     |
| 11 | november         | 0     |
| 12 | december         | 0     |
+----+------------------+-------+
```

I'm assuming my `where year...` clause is the one causing this behaviour, how can I get my query to work as the one I want to achieve?

Comment: Please tell us what your `months` table looks like. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: The months table is basically what the query returns, only the ID and it's name

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Move `YEAR(created_at) = 2018` into the `ON` clause. Also, you can change `COUNT(MONTH(created_at))` to `COUNT(created_at)`.

Comment: @Balmbar that did the trick, nice going!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a left join instead of a right join

```
SELECT months.name as m, 
   IFNULL(Count(created_at), 0) as total 
  from months
  LEFT JOIN ENTRIES ON months.id = MONTH(created_at)
  where YEAR(created_at) = 2018 
  GROUP BY months.id
```

Comment: Yes. But start with the `months` table and `LEFT JOIN` the `entries` table. That pattern ensures there's a row for every month, even though there aren't matching rows in `entries` for some months.

Comment: Good catch @O.Jones  +1 :) I updated my code

Comment: Still getting the same result, it's not returning the values in the column where there are supposed to be a 0 count

Comment: Did you try it with the updated code edit I just made per @O.Jones ?  Notice the table switch from entries to months

Comment: Updated my question, the "created_at" column belongs to entries

Comment: Yep! Still getting the same result, I assume the issue is on the `where YEAR(entries.created_at)` that's only getting the values from the entries column and ignoring the ones where the count of entries.created_at returns 0 because if I remove the `where YEAR(entries.created_at)` it returns what I want, but I'm filtering entries by year

Comment: Haha I think I might see the problem. Remove Month from the count() function while still keeping the tables switched for a left join

Comment: Removing the month also isn't working, I even tried using `count(*)` and that's not working either

Comment: Did you try IFNULL()? Maybe try IFNULL(Count(created_at), 0)

Comment: Yes, I've even tried COALESCE, and it's still excluding the entries where they're supposed to be 0

Comment: `table1 RIGHT JOIN table2` is the same as `table2 LEFT JOIN table1`.